# SQL Server UDF array inputs and outputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, udf

I have a set of columns CODE_1-10, which contain diagnostic codes.  I want to create a set of variables CODE_GROUP_1-17, which indicate whether or not one of some particular set of diagnostic codes matches any of the CODE_1-10 variables.  For example, CODE_GROUP_1 = 1 if any of CODE_1-10 match either '123' or '456', and CODE_GROUP_2 = 1 if any of CODE_1-10 match '789','111','333','444' or 'foo'.

Here's an example of how you could do this using values constructors.

```
    CASE WHEN (SELECT count(value.val)
       FROM    (VALUES (CODE_1)
                   ,   (CODE_2)
                   ,   (CODE_3)
                   ,   (CODE_4)
                   ,   (CODE_5)
                   ,   (CODE_6)
                   ,   (CODE_7)
                   ,   (CODE_8)
                   ,   (CODE_9)
                   ,   (CODE_10)
               ) AS value(val)
     WHERE value.val in ('123', '456')
   ) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CODE_GROUP_1,

   CASE WHEN (SELECT count(value.val)
       FROM    (VALUES (CODE_1)
                   ,   (CODE_2)
                   ,   (CODE_3)
                   ,   (CODE_4)
                   ,   (CODE_5)
                   ,   (CODE_6)
                   ,   (CODE_7)
                   ,   (CODE_8)
                   ,   (CODE_9)
                   ,   (CODE_10)
               ) AS value(val)
     WHERE value.val in ('789','111','333','444','foo')
   ) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CODE_GROUP_2
```

I am wondering if there is another way to do this that is more efficient.  Is there a way to make a CLR UDF that takes an array of CODE_1-10, and outputs a set of columns CODE_GROUP_1-17?

Comment: There is no such thing as an array in SQL Server. Have you considered table-valued parameters (TVPs)? You can pass in structured data from your application (e.g. a DataTable) without any messy de-/re-constructing.

Comment: How can I construct the table-valued parameters to consist of a small table containing CODE_1-10 without copy-pasting "VALUES(...) ..." 17 different times?

Comment: Well, assuming you already have a table type and have declared a local variable called `@tvp`, you can say: `;WITH x AS (SELECT TOP (10) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) FROM master.dbo.spt_values) INSERT @tvp(col) SELECT 'CODE_' + RTRIM(rn) FROM x;` If you want to see what that does, run it without the `INSERT @tvp(col)` bit. I only mentioned TVPs because it *sounded* like your array of values was meant to come from an app, and you were hard-coding it here for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I'll look into that.  My array of values are columns in a huge table, which are named CODE_1-10.  I want to apply this mapping function to each row, and output the result to columns in a select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could at least avoid the repetition of `FROM (VALUES ...)` like this:

```
SELECT
  CODE_GROUP_1 = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN val IN ('123', '456')                  THEN 1 END),
  CODE_GROUP_2 = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN val IN ('789','111','333','444','foo') THEN 1 END),
  ...
FROM
  (
    VALUES
      (CODE_1),
      (CODE_2),
      (CODE_3),
      (CODE_4),
      (CODE_5),
      (CODE_6),
      (CODE_7),
      (CODE_8),
      (CODE_9),
      (CODE_10)
  ) AS value(val)
```

If `CODE_1`, `CODE_2` etc. are column names, you can use the above query as a derived table in CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  dbo.atable  -- table containing CODE_1, CODE_2 etc.
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT ...  -- the above query
  ) AS x
;
```

Comment: This is not what I was thinking about doing, but is a much better solution.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, COUNT(DISTIINCT ... ) so many times actually more than doubled my query time.  When I changed to using the cross apply method but replaced COUNT(DISTINCT ...) with MAX(CASE ... ELSE 0 END), query time went from 21 minutes to 30 seconds.

Comment: @SeanOgden: MAX is a much better replacement indeed. I've both seen and used it myself numerous times, but the idea never crossed my mind last night when I was writing this answer. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create 2 new tables with the columns appended as rows?  So one table would be dxCode with a source column if you need to retain the 1-10 value and the dx code and whatever key field(s) you need, the other table would be dxGroup with your 17 groups, the source groupID if you need it, and your target dx values.
Then to determine which codes are in which groups, you can join on your dx fields.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your solution would require expanding the original table by making up to 10 rows per row of input data.  The key fields are not small, and there are many of them, and the table is very large, so this is not ideal.

Comment: well, the term is 'normalizing,' but yes, you'd have the PK fields, a sourceColumnID field if you need it, and one or more value fields.  The idea is to union the individual non-null values from each of the 10 columns (or 17 groups) before trying to determine which values are in which set.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of normalization, I just wasn't sure that's what you were talking about because the description is confusing.  At any rate, in my case this solution isn't the best option.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: have you tried it?  It's what database servers are optimized to perform with.  On a large scale, it's your only option.  On a small scale, it doesn't matter if you leave it the way you have it.